# How to extract certain db fields from a parent model using STI in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have a Mechanism model, and its schema is something like this:

```
t.string   "image"
t.string   "type"
t.string   "speed"
t.string   "name"
```

Now suppose I would like to create a child model called Car, which fully inherits the Mechanism model fields using STI (`Car < Mechanism`), but also applies its own:

```
t.string   "wheels"
t.string   "metal_type"
t.string   "fuel_consumption"
...
```

In the end I would basically like to have many models, that share certain db field with Mechanism model, and behave like a Mechanism.

Now I know that STI does not work like this, but I would like to know what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the **inheritance** gems.

[acts_as_relation](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation) & [multiple_table_inheritance](https://github.com/mhuggins/multiple_table_inheritance) will help you with your work

Answer (score 1):

One non-STI solution would be to have a 1-M relationship between `Car` and `Mechanism`

```
class Car < AtiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mechanism
end

class Mechanism < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

This would let you do something like

```
car = Car.first

car.mechanism.speed
```

Understanding that is not what you're looking for, check out the [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method.

```
class Car < AtiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mechanism

  delegate :image, :type, :speed, :name, to: :mechanism
end

class Mechanism < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

Now you can do the following

```
car = Car.first

car.speed
```